# Update react native (expo) UI when Firebase event happens

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

In my app, one device scans the QR code on another device. When the code is scanned, I notify Firebase and it updates the database.
Then, what I need is to fire some event on the **scanned** phone so the user will see their QR code was scanned. Perhaps redirect to a "success" screen.

How can you achieve this with Expo, Firebase, and possibly Apollo Server?

Is it done via the expo-notifications bundle? Is it done with Firebase Data Messages? Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Scanned Device's Application is open, then you can simply attach a listener to the database where you store the scanned/is-scanned data when the QR Code gets opened.

That way you will receive a new snapshot once your database entry got updated.

```
const qrCodeReference = firebase.database().ref('qrcodes/' + codeId+ '/gotScanned');
qrCodeReference.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    // get the gotScanned value with snapshot.val();
});
```

This is just a basic example and you have to adjust it based on your database structure and what properties you need to be sure the code got scanned successfully.

You can read more on the possibilites here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Indeed. I was watching this tutorial right after posting the question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E81jfHan8MM It shows an example of listening to the db changes with a chat app. I had no idea you can listen to db changes. That's really neat :)